# Webpack dev server not serving output

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have an application that's structured like this:

```
- root
  - app/
  - config/
  - css/
  - js/
  - public/
  - package.json
  - webpack.config.js
```

The React app is in the `app` folder and I'm publishing to the `public` folder. Here is my `webpack` configuration:

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

var extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin(
    "../css/style.css", {
        allChunks: true
    });

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
    entry: {
        withify: '../app/main.jsx',
        fbauth: '../app/fbauth.jsx',
        fbuser: '../app/fbuser.jsx',
        fontawesome: 'font-awesome-webpack!../node_modules/font-awesome-webpack/font-awesome.config.js',
        styles: './css/style.scss'
    },
    output: {
        path: './js',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            config: path.join(__dirname, 'config', process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
        }
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json'
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
                    plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: extractSass.extract(["css", "sass"])
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i,
                loader: 'url'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "file-loader"
            }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        }),
        extractSass
    ],
    externals: {
        fs: '{}',
        tls: '{}',
        net: '{}',
        console: '{}'
    }
};
```

Here is how I'm trying to start the app with `npm run dev`:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base public --inline --hot"
},
```

However, when my `index.html` tries to access the `withify.js` file that should be available in memory in the development server I'm getting a 404; what did I do wrong here?

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Withify Application</title>
  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas ================================================== -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAlPNWOZmv60OUaD3_idHMP15-Ghwm7RDE&libraries=places"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/withify.js"></script>
  <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok well a couple things:

Context is the folder where you tell webpack where to look for your entries.  So currently you are telling webpack to look into the public folder, but all of your entries live in "/app"

So your context would be something like:

```
context: path.join(_dirname, 'app')
```

This tells webpack look into root/app and find the entries which should now look like:

```
entry: [
        withify: 'main.jsx',
        fbauth:  'fbauth.jsx',
        fbuser:  'fbuser.jsx',
       ]
```

And your output will be something like this:

```
output:[
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'js')
        filename: '[name].js' 
       ]
```

I think that should fix your issues as long as you are pulling everything from your public folder!

**EDIT:**

Try setting this as well in your output:

```
output:[
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'js'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/js/' 
       ]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that results in the same error. I wonder why it won't serve the file via the `webpack-dev-server`?

Comment: Can you see withify.js inside your /public/js folder?

Comment: No, it doesn't produce any output, but that's not surprising because that's what it's supposed to do; it should be serving the file from memory.

Comment: Err duh, you're right.  I forgot I have mine setup to actually write my files to the public folder to render routes server-side.  The only thing I can think of is do you have a "/js" directory in your public folder?

Comment: Is it not working after setting the `publicPath` and a global path? I think the output files should be working with this. However, I am not sure your WebpackDevServer is serving your CSS. Are you getting them?

Comment: This post has nothing to do with CSS.  You can add this `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">` in your html file and server css that way, you can do it with webpack as well but again, has nothing to do with this post.